# Ruby on Rails - Connect back to app database after SSH Tunnel query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, devise

I'm connecting to a remote database through an SSH Tunnel inside an Activerecord::Base called Item.

I have:

```
require 'net/ssh/gateway'
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "[table_name]"
  @gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new(host, username)
  @port = @gateway.open('127.0.0.1', 3306, 3309)

 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   adapter: 'mysql2',
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   username: username,
   password: password,
   database: remote_db_name,
   port: @port
 )
```

Then, in a controller I can successfully call for example `Item.all` and retrieve all the items from that remote table. The problem is that then I go to another view of the app (I'm using devise for the users) and I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table '[remote_database_name].users' doesn't exist: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

How do I connect back to the local database? I tried using `@gateway.shutdown!` and `@gateway.close(@port)` with methods from the controller, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`, call `establish_connection` on `Item` class instead:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection { # your connection options here }
end
```

Or, if you have no other choice, then store local database connection options somewhere before calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` and then connect local database manually using stored configuration:

```
@local_db = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
@remote_db = {
  adapter: 'mysql2',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  username: username,
  password: password,
  database: remote_db_name,
  port: @port
}
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(@remote_db)

# when you need your local database again:
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(@local_db)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! But now I deployed the Rails App into an Amazon EC2 and when I try to connect I get "Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed", which is weird because I can connect through SSH using the console of the EC2 instance

Comment: My guess is that your server is run by another system user which therefore has different ssh key. You can check it by running `ps u | grep your_server_name`. For example, If you are using `puma` in your project: `ps u | grep puma`. The first column of output will containt user name. Compare it to your user name. Also, I think you'd better create another question with this issue so that amazon experts will be able to help you